# for loop php shows "Array"

Tags: php, mysql

so i want my php shows list of my database with for loop, when i use it happens like this:

[image: result of my current condition]

here its my coding for it, i know its not good and vulnerable but i just want to know hor loop works in php

```
<?php
    include "db.php";

    $id_pemesanan = 'DDN E/40202003201907323';
    $Barang = $_POST['Barang'];
    $Jumlah = $_POST['Jumlah'];

    $queryResult = $connect->query("SELECT Barang FROM Odr_Msk_Detail WHERE id_pemesanan = '".$id_pemesanan."'");

    $result=array();

    while($fetchData=$queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
        $result[]=$fetchData;
    }
    $jumlah = count($result);

    for ($x = 0;$x <= $jumlah;$x++){
        echo $result[$x];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `echo $result[$x];` => `echo $result[$x]['Barang'];` -- you need to access the column, not just the row.

Comment: Alternatively, you can replace `$result[]=$fetchData;` with `$result[]=$fetchData['Barang'];` and keep your loop as-is. I would use the first approach in my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive that, because you try to echo an array and not a string.

To output everything you could do following, because it is not neccessary to fetch all results and keep them into memory.

```php
while($fetchData = $queryResult->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo join('<br>', $fetchData);
}
```